# Find the smallest element greater than current element

Tags: algorithms, arrays

my question is that given a list of integers (lets say A), for each element A[i], find the smallest element A[j] which could satisfy A[i] < A[j] and i < j. Return -1 if there is no such element.

For example, given [4,2,1,9,3], return [9,3,3,-1,-1]

I have come up with a brute force solution which costs $O(n^2)$, but I'm wondering if there could be a more efficient solution.

Comment: How difficult would this problem be if you had an array of integers, sorted in ascending order?

Comment: I believe that this could be done in as little as O(n)! I'll elaborate when I have access to a computer.

Comment: I think my solution is wrong; the minimum time complexity must be O(n log n) I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution would be using a balanced binary search tree.
You can process the elements from the right to left and for each element you find the vertex in the tree with the smallest key greater than this element (a search query on the tree suffice) and then you add the element to the tree.
Total complexity is $O(n\log(n))$ since we are iterating over the elements once and having one query and one insert operations in each iteration.